# Call math functions ACOS, SIN, COS in Raw query ORM-lite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am wanting to do a search for distributors near on my map . I'm doing a native query search, but is experiencing an error : *SQLiteException : no such function : ACOS ( code 1 )* and ends up showing no distributor on my map. My code is below. Can someone help me?

```
try{
            Dao<Distribuidor, Integer> dao = getDatabase(context).getDao(Distribuidor.class);
            String query=
                    "SELECT * FROM Distribuidor" +
                            " WHERE habilitado = 1" +
                            " AND ((ACOS(SIN(" + lat + " * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(" +
                            lat + " * PI() / 180) * COS(o.lat * PI() / 180) * COS((" + lng +
                    " - o.lng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) <= " + max;


            GenericRawResults<Distribuidor> rawResults = dao.queryRaw(query, dao.getRawRowMapper());
            List<Distribuidor> distribuidores = rawResults.getResults();
            rawResults.close();

            return distribuidores;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I've tried that solution through the C library and not getting results.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I would suggest to perform the operations in your code, using Math-class.